# Drawing line to indicate significance in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, graphics, tidyverse

Hello everybody out there using ggplot,

In order to indicate a significant difference between two groups in a plot, a line and asterisks are often drawn between the groups.
While this is rather easy in base graphics, the situation becomes more difficult when using ggplot.
For indicating significant differences across facets, there has already been asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690007/ggplot-drawing-line-between-points-across-facets) before.
I get the basic idea there, but I'm wondering whether there is a easier way in general and especially a more transparent way to get the coordinates right.

Moreover, I would be very interested in finding a good tutorial on using `gtable`. The answer to the question above relies on `gtable`, but the manual is rather short for a beginner.

Comment: Within facets, instead of across facets, contrasts can be indicated with: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble envisioning the problem, are you able to provide an example of the current behaviour, and what you'd like the plot to look like?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a while ago. Anyone having been forwarded to this question might want to try the `ggsignif` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html, which offers suitable functionality.