# Nested facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create nested facets. In the example below, there are 4 experiments. Each experiment has 2 subjects with 2 test scores. I would still like each `subj_num` on a separate plot, but for each `subj_num` in a given `exp_num` to be linked, with a facet that extends across both plots. Is this possible?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(exp_num = rep(1:4, each=4),
                  subj_num = rep(1:8, each=2),
                  test_num = rep(1:2, 2),
                  score = sample(16)
                  )

ggplot(dat, aes(test_num, score)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(exp_num+subj_num~.)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you see questions like these already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690007/ggplot-drawing-line-between-points-across-facets What exactly did you try and where are you getting stuck? I'm not sure I understand what your desired output for this data is.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

`dat <- dat %>% mutate(new = as.factor(paste(exp_num,subj_num)))

ggplot(dat, aes(test_num, score)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~new)`

Comment: Thanks for these. What I'm trying to show is that the two subjects in each experiment are linked. I know I can plot them on the same chart, but I need them on separate plots. Whether those two plots have a parent facet showing the exp_num, or those two are closer together. The key is to show that each subj is essentially in a group covered by exp_num.